# LINQ Update or Insert objects into List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Ok, so I have a List that contains a collection of message objects. An updated list of message objects comes in every 60 seconds. Some of the objects in the first collection will have updated data based on an ID property inside each object.

```
public class Message
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }
}
```

How in LINQ can I Insert in the updated object based on the Id?

Comment: Is this Linq To Sql? Linq to Entities? It's also not clear what you're asking. "Inserting" and "Updating" objects are two different operations. "Inserting" generally means "creating a new instance" and "Updating" means "updating an existing one."

Comment: Nope... LINQ to objects. Well in this case, it would be updating.

Comment: LINQ cannot insert or update objects.  It can only _query_ for objects.

Comment: @JohnH It can query for the items that need to be updated.

Comment: @Servy Right, but that's not what was asked.

Comment: Its a small amount of changes. My thought was to remove those with updates and just insert in the new object.

Comment: Well I guess that I can handle myself. I wasn't sure if LINQ was able to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to the object Message.

Something like this:

```
this.Messages.ForEach(mess => {

  if(mess.Id == someValue){
      // do something here
  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Message> LocalList;
List<Message> ArrivingList;
var mergedItems = LocalList.Contcat(ArrivingList);
mergedItems = (from msg in mergedItems
               group msg by msg.Id into grp
               let sameKey = mergedItems.Where(obj => obj.Id == grp.Id)
               select sameKey.Where(obj => obj.MessageDate == grp.Max(obj2 => obj2.MessageDate)).Single()).ToList();
LocalList = (List<Message>)mergedItems;
```

I think something similar to the above would probably "work" but I would just use a standard Dictionary /List and write a small updating routine.  Just because you CAN do something with a particular tool does not mean you SHOULD.

For me LINQ based stuff can be MUCH harder to troubleshoot, understand, debug, trace, evaluate, etc. 
(Replace LocalList and ArrivingList in the above example with whatever your actual variable are)